cleaning/fixing igniter on GE gas cooktop
We have a GE Profile Gas Downdraft cooktop (PGP990SENSS) with an additional cooktop module (JXGB90S) installed in 2013.  The knob has to be turned 6-7 times (with a click each time) before finally lighting a burner.  What is the best way of cleaning this unit?  It seems it is sealed and the manual says clean with kitchen towel and that does not seem to suffice.
link

You have to clean the ignitor electrode.  If more than one of the burners is having the same problem, your cooktop is the right age for this problem to be happening.  When you clean the stainless steel, or a  frying pan - sometimes there are very stubborn bits right?   Same goes for the electrode, except it's tiny and you can't see it so it never gets cleaned.  All the more so on your "sealed burner" one where you REALLY can't see it.  Use a stiff toothbrush, steel wool, a little oven cleaner, dish soap ... it doesn't matter.  Just clean the thing without damaging it.  It will spark back to life.  :)    How exactly you access the thing to do that on a sealed burner, I'm not sure, but maybe you remove the whole sealed burner unit (see instructions on line) so you can take it somewhere and get better light and better angles on it.
You have to make sure all the little holes around each burner are free of debris, especially the one facing the ignitor.  On a normal (not sealed) burner this is easy.  You remove them and clean them in the sink.  On your sealed one, you have to peer around, look closely, and use a toothpick to clean all the holes regardless of whether or not you see anything.

On gas stoves, the ignition ports can get clogged with food debris.  The ports being clogged obviously reduces the flow rate of gas to the igniter, which makes it harder to fire.
See around 0:20 in this video.
I don't think the burner caps are sealed—you should be able to remove those and access the ignition ports.
